# AndroidRuntime(1130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

Please need help on this.When I am trying to run my app on emulator I got these error in my Logcat and my UI Crashes

**logcat errors**

```
07-04 15:54:08.453: W/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x2bd39930)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
{com.example.giftfinder/com.example.giftfinder.SettingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.example.giftfinder.SettingActivity.<init>(SettingActivity.java:18)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-04 15:54:08.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     ... 11 more
```

This my SettingActivity.java file.When I click a button in my Mainactivity file that will show this activity which actually crashes because or errors..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class SettingActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner him;
    Spinner her;
    TableRow tr2;
    TableRow tr3;
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    //private String[] mystring;
    Resources res = getResources();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        tr2=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tr2);
        tr3=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tr3);
        him=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.himspinner);
        her=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.herspinner);
}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view)
{
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.him:
        if(checked){
            tr2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            him.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.himentries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            him.setAdapter(adapter);
            her.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.her:
    if(checked){
        tr2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        him.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.herentries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        him.setAdapter(adapter);
        her.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);      
    }
    break;
    case R.id.couples:
        if(checked){
        tr2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
    }
    break;
    default:
        tr2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}

}
```

My settings.xml file

```
<
```

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/background">

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

       <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/tr1">

           <TextView 
               android:id="@+id/gender"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/gender"
               android:textSize="25sp"
               android:paddingLeft="20dp"
               android:paddingTop="10dp"
               android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               />
           <RadioGroup 
               android:id="@+id/rg1"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="15dp">
           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/him"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/him"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/her"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/her"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/couples"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/couples"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

           </RadioGroup>
       </TableRow>


       <TableRow 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tr2"
           >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
                android:text="@string/relation"
                android:textSize="25sp" 
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
               android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/himspinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"

                android:prompt="@string/himprompt"
                />

           <Spinner 
               android:id="@+id/herspinner"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:entries="@array/herentries"
               android:prompt="@string/herprompt"
               android:visibility="invisible"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

       </TableRow>
       <TableRow
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tr3"
            android:visibility="invisible" >
        <TextView 
               android:id="@+id/category"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/category"
               android:textSize="25sp"
               android:paddingLeft="20dp"
               android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
           <RadioGroup 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="15dp">
           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/occ"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/occ"
               android:textSize="15sp"/>

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/feel"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/feel"
               android:textSize="15sp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
             </RadioGroup> 

       </TableRow>

      <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tr4"
            android:visibility="invisible">


          <Spinner 
              android:id="@+id/occspinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:entries="@array/occentries"
                android:prompt="@string/occprompt"/>


          <Spinner 
              android:id="@+id/feelspinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:entries="@array/feelentries"
                android:prompt="@string/feelprompt"/>

       </TableRow>

      <TableRow
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tr5" 
            android:visibility="invisible">
          <TextView 
               android:id="@+id/age"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/age"
               android:textSize="25sp" 
               android:paddingLeft="20dp"
               android:paddingTop="10dp"/>


          <Spinner 
              android:id="@+id/agespinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:entries="@array/ageentries"
                android:prompt="@string/ageprompt"/>
      </TableRow>

</TableLayout>`

>

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.. Please post some portion of your code (Specially the `SettingActivity.java` file's line 18) so we can know what the problem might be and help you.

Comment: And can you please tell us what is your line 18? It's hard here for us to count lines and we can't accurately know which line it is. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put code in `SettingsActivity`'s constructor, that's wrong, don't write any code in the constructors of Application Components (Like activities and services). Not everything is already created there, in your case - the `Resources` object is not created yet. Move your code to `onCreate` instead, and it will work fine.

Comment: Actually What I am trying to do is firstly if someone click the Radio button either HIM or HER named radio button,that will shows a hidden Textview below it called Realtionship with spinner.I want the value of spinner take from array..But I am getting this all logcat error..

Comment: ..Thank you so much..It worked..I did , I put the whole code in onCreate method and It started working...

Comment: Great :) You see, the problem was calling `getResources` in the field declaration (Which actually moves into the constructor). Simply avoid doing anything before `Activity.onCreate` executes.